# How to schedule a method with TimerTask but with different method parameter the first time

Tags: java, parameters, timer, schedule, timertask

This is the first time I post something in the beautiful and awesome StackOverflow community and my english is a bit rusty, but I'll try to explain the best I can.

I have the following situation:

In my main, I'm invoking a method through a TimerTask, because I need to schedule it so the method is executed every 5 seconds. Here is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                methodWithParams("HelloWorld");
            }
        };
        
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 5000);

    }
```

And here is the invoked method:

```
public static void methodWithParams(String param){
    System.out.println("Incoming Param: "+param);
}
```

With this, the output is like this every 5 seconds:

```
Incoming Param: HelloWorld
```

What I want is to run *methodWithParams* method every 5 seconds, but the first time that method is invoked, I can call it with some param but the rest of the time the param is anything else, so the result is something like this:

```
Incoming Param: HelloWorld
Incoming Param: HelloWorld2
Incoming Param: HelloWorld2
Incoming Param: HelloWorld2
```

How can I do that? Any suggests?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: I don't quite understand one thing: do you want to be able to change the parameter at any point, or just change the parameter after the first task execution? Do you would know what the second parameter value is going to be up-front?

Comment: Sorry. I deleted the post since I found out the solution and I realized the question was a bit dumb. I'll edit the post to include the solution, so it can be available if someone has the same doubt like I had. Thank you!

Comment: Rather than including your solution into the question body, please make it an answer. You can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem and I deleted the post (my fault). I undeleted so the solution can be available for someone who has the same question I had.

What I did was this: By creating a boolean class var inside the task, I was able to control if it was the first execution or not since the task behaves like a loop.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        boolean first = true;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            if(first){
                first = false;
                methodWithParams("HelloWorld");
            }else{
                methodWithParams("HelloWorld2");
            }
        }
    };
    
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 5000);

}
```